# How to select only certain items from a collection using Streams in Java

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I am trying to select only names from a collection using streams: These are the entries:

```
Person{id=4, name=E, color=red}] 
[Person{id=0, name=A, color=blue}
Person{id=1, name=B, color=green}
Person{id=2, name=D, color=pink}
Person{id=0, name=C, color=yellow
```

I've tried using map, but it doesn't seem to alter the list since the function I'm mapping it to is supposed to be a getter method.

```
list.stream().map(p -> getter.apply(p))collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Use a `filter` operation..?

Comment: Does something like `map(p -> p.getName())` not work?

Comment: @Slaw I think they want to use map instead, to get just the names, not filter by a condition

Comment: provide more information, it's not possible to resolve your issue with the provided details.

Comment: @user Possibly. Though the title of the question implies the desire to filter.

Comment: @bunny Please [edit] your question to clarify what exactly you want. Include a [mre] demonstrating the problem along with sample input and output.

Comment: @Slaw Yeah, it's confusing. I thought that too, but then I read the sentence "I am trying to select only names"

Comment: I'm trying to select only names from this list and then put it into a new collection, but it just returns the same collection as before.

Comment: @bunny_eitak What output did you get?

Comment: @bunny Your question already says that, so obviously restating your question using the same words is not going to help clarify things if we're already confused (your question title suggests "filter" but your question body suggests "map"). Note we all speak code here; providing a [mre] and sample input and output would help us understand.

Comment: `collect(toList())` returns a new list. It doesn't update your original list. You're ignoring the return value.

Answer (score 2):

If you have getter defined for the fields of Person, you can map the names:

```
List<String> personNames = list.stream().map(Person::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.filter`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-collection-filtering), like the webiste explains you, instead of `.map`

Answer (score 0):

To filter say on the `name`, do it like this.

```
Person{id=4, name=E, color=red}] 
[Person{id=0, name=A, color=blue}
Person{id=1, name=B, color=green}
Person{id=2, name=D, color=pink}
Person{id=0, name=C, color=yellow
```

Assuming a `List<Person>`

To get all the Person objects with a specific name

```
List<Person> specific = list
                   .stream()
                   .filter(person->person.name.equals("E"))
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

To get just the names

```
List<String> names = list
               .stream()
               .map(person->person.name)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's what the OP wants. Something more like Alex Rudenko's answer

Comment: Did they? It still said that they wanted to select only the names, though, right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic code, that uses filter:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Person {
  int id;
  String name;
  String color;
  
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return id + ":" + name + ":" + color;
  }
  public Person(int id, String name, String color) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
  }
  public int getId() {return id;}
  public void setId(int id) {this.id = id;}
  public String getName() {return name;}
  public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
  public String getColor() {return color;}
  public void setColor(String color) {this.color = color;}
}

public class Test {
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
    list.add(new Person(1,"Ana","red"));
    list.add(new Person(2,"tna","orange"));
    list.add(new Person(3,"Hna","green"));
    list.add(new Person(4,"Ana","blue"));
    
    List<Person> t = list.stream().filter(p->p.getName().equals("Ana")).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(t);
  }

}
```

For this particular question it is suggestible to use filter instead of map. Because we are only interested in filtering the stream to get the desired output.
On the other hand, map operation is used on the stream if we have the requirement to manipulate the data further in which condition we can apply more functions before the terminal operation (example is provided).

By using map, you transform the object values.

The map operation allows us to apply a function, that takes in a parameter of one type, and returns something else.

For an example:

```
Stream students = persons.stream()
      .filter(p -> p.getAge() > 18)
      .map(new Function<Person, Customer>() { 
                  @Override
                  public Customer apply(Person person) {
                     return new Customer(person);
                  }
              });
```

Filter is used for filtering the data, it always returns the boolean value. If it returns true, the item is added to list else it is filtered out.

For in-depth understanding follow the documentation
[link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)